# MySql, How to display data that was entered in the last 3 hours?

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to output recent data that was entered to the DB in the last Three hours, for that I have done this :

```
SELECT * FROM  `tableName` WHERE DATE <= TIMEDIFF (  'SYSDATE()',  '03:00:00' )
```

But it does NOT worked for me, any ideas on how I can do it ?

Comment: Does your table have an attribute that stores the creation of each entry?

Comment: What do you mean by `stores the creation of each entry` ? I have 5 attributes in my table.

Comment: Which attributes are those?

Comment: sysdate is oracle syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this :)

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
where Date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 3 HOUR);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `timestampdiff` on your date column.

```
SELECT * FROM  tableName 
WHERE timestampdiff( HOUR, date, now() ) <= 3
```

Provided your column `date` must be of type `datetype` or `timestamp`

Comment: @user3405229: Can you explain what difference you found?